# Visualizar varios docs html en la misma ventana y pestaña del navegador

Tags: python, python-3.x, navegador-web

Muy buenas a todos.
Estoy intentando que los archivos html contenidos en una carpeta se muestren en el navegador por turnos (30 segundos cada uno, por ejemplo), pero siempre en la misma ventana y pestaña, sustituyéndose unos por otros.
Hasta ahora he probado con webbbrowser, utilizando Firefox, Chrome y Chromiun, pero no hay manera. O bien se me abren los archivos en ventanas nuevas o en pestañas nuevas. Dejo el código por si a alguien se le ocurriera otra solución:

```
from os import scandir, getcwd
import webbrowser
import time
ruta = getcwd()
lista = [doc.name for doc in scandir(ruta) if doc.is_file() and doc.name.endswith(".html")]
for doc in lista:
    doc = ruta + '\\' + doc
    webbrowser.open(doc, new=0)
    time.sleep(30)
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Ha conseguido al menos cerrar las ventanas a medida que no se necesitan con wmctrl. El problema ahora es que, de esta forma, no se pueden reproducir en pantalla completa. ¿Alguien conoce algún comando que pasar a través de subprocess o de os.system, que abra firefox en modo pantalla compelta?
Dejo el código hasta el momento

```
import os
import time
import webbrowser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    docs = [doc.name for doc in os.scandir(path='./templates') if doc.is_file() and doc.name.endswith('.html')]
    emp = 'Servicios Médicos Santa Cruz'
    firefox = webbrowser.get('firefox')
    i = 0
    for doc in docs:
        print(doc)
        firefox.open('localhost:8000/{}/{}'.format(emp, doc), new=0)
        time.sleep(6)
        if i != 0:
            os.system('wmctrl -c Mozilla Firefox')
        i += 1
```